# How to add external javascript through a secure connection on Magento

Tags: magento

I own a magento store. I have a special javascript which is triggered on checkout success page. That javascript is needed to be externally loaded. But when I enable https it fails.

Does running an external javascript through a secure connection conflict with the nature of https connections? Anyone has a comment or solution for this?

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit? Is your success page in https too? Is your script available in https? I mean, when you access to the URL, does it returns a 404?

Comment: Haltabush, my store is in magento defaults and its success page is naturally appears in https. Even though no errors including 404 appears, my script can not reach to the external source. External source does not receive any request from my magento store. That is the problem. Is there a way to turn success page into a http one?

Comment: Using https shouldn't be a problem, even if you don't use the same certificate. I do the same all the time (to load jquery from Google, for example). Did you try to actually display the source code of the external JS? (to do that, just copy/past its url in you browser's address bar)

Comment: Haltabush, your experience helped me solve the case. You are right. Https is not a problem for external sources. The problem in my case is the filtration of the server that accepts external clients to use its sources. That filter learned url's that start with https, and voila problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

Please include the js in the layout/checkout.xml .

One page checkout main layout

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs"><script>check/checkout.js</script></action>
 </reference>
```